# What is the best consumer grade hardware for litecoin mining?

Tags: litecoin, mining-hardware

I want to start litecoin mining and have following questions:

1. Given that I already have a desktop, and with the investment of < 500$ for GPUs, what is the best hardware to mine litecoins?
2. Is it worth mining litecoins with such hardware?
3. Are ASICs available for litecoin mining? If not, any possibility of them coming soon?

Comment: Are you stuck to litecoins? Because mining other scrypt based altcoins can yield some nice profit if you're careful to exchange to bitcoin quickly. For example, with a $200 graphics card (R270X) you can get around $4/day mining whatever [coinwarz](http://www.coinwarz.com/cryptocurrency) says to mine (you can use multipools to automate this as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given that I already have a desktop, and with the investment of < 500$ for GPUs, what is the best hardware to mine litecoins?

You would probably want to invest in 1 AMD Radeon card, for example 280x or 290. This is private opinion based, but AMD seems to provide good hash rate for money. Have a look at [litecoin hardware comparison](https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison) site for the estimated hash rate.

> Is it worth mining litecoins with such hardware?

If you can get around 750 KH/s, this would yield around $130 over 30 days ([source](https://www.litecoinpool.org/calc?hashrate=750&difficulty=3931.59487261&power=50&energycost=0.10&currency=USD)). Note the price is fluctuating a lot, so by no means this is set in stone.

> Are ASICs available for litecoin mining?

No, there aren't at the moment. It takes time to develop and test custom circuit. Not advertising here, but [this company](https://alpha-t.net/terms-order/) appears to offer two models: 5 MH/s (£1350) and 25 MH/s (£5450) with the release date due in Q2-Q3 2014. It's up to you if you would trust them and pay a deposit. Obviously, there will be many others cooking similar stuff in the next half a year (Q1-Q2 2014).

Comment: Yield $130 over what time period?

Comment: Edited the answer. It's over 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend getting your parts from [Litecoin Mining Parts](http://www.litecoinminingparts.com) as they are pretty reliable with the powered riser cables and other bits. They also have a ASIC miner that mines LTC!

Comment: Last that I heard there was an ASIC miner for Scrypt announced, but later this turned out to be vapor. I am pretty sure that I would have read about it, if a Scrypt ASIC had actually been on the market. Could you please show your work on that?

Comment: Explored their site. Very interesting! But indeed found no mention at all of an ASIC nowhere in their site.